# How to create a doubly linked list of integers in ascending sorted order?

Tags: c++

I'm having hard time to finish the code to get the following steps:

1. how to read in a file of positive integers (>0)?
2. how to create a doubly linked list of integers in ascending sorted order?
3. how to write a method to print the entire list in ascending or descending order (input parameter ‘A’ or ‘D’ tells direction to print)?
4. how notify the user with a message if the number to add is already in the list or if the number is not in the list if they to delete a number not in the list.

**There's no error when i run the program, just trying to solve the 4 steps above.**

Here's what I have done so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
struct  node
{
    int number; 
    node *next; 
};
bool isEmpty(node *head); 
char menu(); 
void insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&last, int number);
void inser(node*&head, node*&last, int number);
void remove(node *&head, node *&last);
void showlist(node *current);
int numIntElement(ifstream&x);
int main() {

    string filename;
    cout << " Please enter the name of the file = "; 
    cin >> filename; 
    ifstream myfile; 
    myfile.open(filename); 
    if (!myfile.is_open()) {
        cout << endl << " failed to open file, check that it exists and you have access \n" << "\n" << endl; 

    }
    else if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        ifstream x;
        numIntElement(x); 
        cout << " File exists \n";
        ////
        node * head = NULL;
        node *last = NULL;
        char choice;
        int number;
        do {
            choice = menu();
            switch (choice)
            {
            case '1':
                cout << " Please enter number : ";
                cin >> number;
                inser(head, last, number);
                break;
            case '2':
                remove(head, last);
            case '3':
                showlist(head);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        } while (choice != '4');
        {

        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
int numIntElement(ifstream&x) {

    int n = 0;
    int m; 
    ifstream myfile("file.txt");
    int countsingfie = 0;

    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
        myfile >> n;
        countsingfie += n;
        if (countsingfie == 0) {
            cout << "Error : file exist but no data " << endl;
        }
        cout << "total number " << countsingfie << "\n" << endl;
        return countsingfie;
    }
}
bool isEmpty(node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        return true; 
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
char menu() {
    char choice; 
    cout << " Main Menu \n"; 
    cout << " 1 . Add a number \n";
    cout << " 2 . Delete a number from the list \n";
    cout << " 3 . Show the list \n"; 
    cout << " 4.  Exit \n";
    cin >> choice; 
    return choice;
}
void insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&last, int number) {
    node *temp = new node; 
    temp->number = number; 
    temp->next = NULL; 
    head = temp; 
    last = temp; 
}
void inser(node*&head, node*&last, int number) {
    if (isEmpty(head)>0){
        insertAsFirstElement(head, last, number); 
    }
    else if (isEmpty(head) < 0)
    {
        cout << " Please enter a number above 0 " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp->number = number;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}
void remove(node *&head, node *&last) {
    if (isEmpty(head)) {
        cout << " Sorry, The list is already empty \n"; 

    }
    else if (head == last)
    { 
        delete head; 
        head = NULL;
        last = NULL; 

    }
    else
    {
        node *temp = head; 
        head = head->next; 
        delete temp; 
    }
}
void showlist(node *current) {

    if (isEmpty(current)) {
        cout << " The list is empty \n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " The list contains: \n "; 
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            cout << current->number << endl; 
            current = current->next; 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have a "return countsingfie" inside the while loop, this will stop the loop so that only one number will be read.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Are you getting an error in the compilation or the output somewhere? What have you done to attempt to debug it? There is no actual problem statement here.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm not getting any error in the compilation, I'm having hard time to finish the code to get the following step...-how to read in a file of positive integers (>0) ?
2-how to create a doubly linked list of integers in ascending sorted order? 3-how to write a method to print the entire list in ascending or descending order (input parameter ‘A’ or ‘D’ tells direction to print)? 4-how notify the user with a message if the number to add is already in the list or if the number is not in the list if they to delete a number not in the list.

Comment: @AssamAl-Zookery. Please edit your question with a specific problem. "I am having a problem, fix this for me" is not going to work on SO unless you tell us what to fix. Do not do it in the comments.

Comment: Things like detailed description of debugging steps and expected vs actual outputs are not just recommended. They are required for a complete question. Dumping a bunch of code and requirements is not going to fly.

Comment: You have a lot of code, but also a lot of things you say you need help on. Try focusing on one thing at a time and ask one question at a time with the minimum code you have that shows the problem.